# How to add percentage sign to eval() result?

Tags: python-3.x

So I am trying to insert a percentage sign at the end of my output for the variable rate. However I am getting a "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'" error." How do I format the output so that I could put a '%' sign on it.

```
Loan = eval(input("Enter loan amount, for example 120000: "))

while Loan <= 12000 or Loan >= 125000:
    print("Please enter a value more than 120000 or less than 125000")
    Loan = eval(input("Enter loan amount, for example 120000: "))
Year = eval(input("Enter number of years as an integer, for example 7: "))

while Year < 5 or Year >10:
    print("Please enter a number more than 5 or less than 10")
    Year = eval(input("Enter number of years as an integer, for example 7: "))

print('%-20s%-20s%-20s' % ('Interest Rate', 'Monthly Payment', 'Total Payment'))

Rate = 5.0
while Rate <= 8:
    adjRate = Rate / 1200
    monthlyPayment = Loan * adjRate / (1 - 1 / (1 + adjRate) ** (Year * 12))
    totalPayment = monthlyPayment * Year * 12
    print('%-20.3f%-20.2f%-20.2f' % (Rate, monthlyPayment, totalPayment))
    Rate += 0.125
```

I tried:
`print('%-20.3f%-20.2f%-20.2f' % (Rate+'%', monthlyPayment, totalPayment))`

but got an

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'"
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `Rate` is a float and `'%'` is a str, the expression

```
Rate + '%'
```

is indeed illegal: in Python, you cannot "add" a float and a str.

So that's the cause of the specific error you inquired about. To fix it, you can do the following:

```
print('%20.3f%s%20.2f%20.2f' % (Rate, '%', monthlyPayment, totalPayment))
```

So that the `%s` in the format string gets you the `%`.

I also removed the negative signs, as numbers should generally be right aligned.

If you are using Python 3.6 or above I highly recommend writing this as:

```
print(f'{Rate:20.3f}%{monthlyPayment:20.2f}{totalPayment:20.2f'})
```

Again, this just answers the reason for your error. The use of `eval` is actually another matter; it should not be used the way you used it here. (Just pointing that out since I feel an obligation to do so.)

Answer (score 2):

Never use eval on user input, use input and validate what is entered; otherwise this opens up so many security holes.

Instead use conversion commands like `float()` and `int()`.

So, for example:

```
loan_str = input("Enter loan amount")
loan_amt = int(loan_amt)
```

Wrap everything in try/except to catch people putting in "fifty thousand" instead of "50000"

This will also ensure that your values are the correct type for your code.

To embed a '%' in your string use '%%'

Answer (score 0):

Just use `print("what ever you want here", end = "%")`